# How do I make my program not close until instructed [Distance Conversion]

Tags: java, distance

I can't seem to figure out where or what to type input the while loop.
Everything works fine, but after I input a conversion, how do I make it ask me if I want to input another problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DistanceConversion 
{ 
    public static void showKilometers(double meters)
    {
        double kilometers = meters * 0.001; 
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + kilometers + " kilometers."); 
    } 

    public static void showInches(double meters) 
    { 
        double inches = meters * 39.37; 
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + inches + " inches."); 
    } 

    public static void showFeet(double meters) 
    { 
        double feet = meters * 3.281; 
        System.out.println(meters +" meters is " + feet + " feet."); 
    } 

    public static void quitProgram() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
        System.out.println(0); 
    } 
    public static void showMenu() 
    { 
        System.out.println(" 1. Convert to kilometers "); 
        System.out.println(" 2. Convert to inches "); 
        System.out.println(" 3. Convert to feet "); 
        System.out.println(" 4. Quit the program "); 
        System.out.println(" "); 
    } 

    public static void main (String [] args) 
    { 
        double meters; 
        int choice; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter a distance in meters: "); 
        meters = scan.nextDouble(); 
        showMenu(); 
        choice = scan.nextInt(); 

        switch(choice) 
        { 
            case 1:showKilometers(meters); 
            break; 
            case 2:showInches(meters); 
            break; 
            case 3:showFeet(meters); 
            break; 
            case 4:quitProgram(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to repeat? The whole program? Then enclose the "whole program" aka. the main logic with a while loop, checking whether input equals 4 or some other arbitrary exit int.

declare "int choice" at the top, then enclose the rest in a while.

```
while(choice >= 1 && choice <=3)
{
   //main-method code here
}
```

Edit (for clarity):

```
int choice = 0; 
while(choice != 4)
{
        double meters; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter a distance in meters: "); 
        meters = scan.nextDouble(); 
        showMenu(); 
        choice = scan.nextInt(); 

        switch(choice) 
        { 
            case 1:showKilometers(meters); 
            break; 
            case 2:showInches(meters); 
            break; 
            case 3:showFeet(meters); 
            break; 
            case 4:quitProgram(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wanted it to keep asking me until I chose option 4 " Quit program. "

Comment: Using the while-loop I used as example it will quit if you input anything but 1 to 3. If you want 4 specifically just use; "while(choice != 4)".

Comment: Maybe I'm playing it incorrectly, but now when pick choice 1-3 theres a huge loop going on that fills up the whole screen repeatedly with the answer.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the code carefully and try understand how it works, so that you'll learn something from it till next time ;).

Comment: Yeah, Until I saw how it was really done. I had no idea where to place the while loop or what to enclose it with. You definitely helped me. It makes sense when "choice is not equal to 4" that it should repeat.